# how to change the teradata server port number?

Tags: teradata, database-administration

The default port for teradata is 1025. I want to change that.

I have launched the teradata server on ec2. I tried to change it via the "Teradata Administrator Tool", but it does not have such an option.

I could not find any teradata admin tools/tutorials that explains how to change the default port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, we cannot change the port number. (Checked with teradata support)